# .htaccess redirection rule to redirect similar URLs with different structure

Tags: php, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need to rewrite a rule in a .htaccess. I have users coming from google to my old site links that doesn't exist anymore.

Old site:

```
oldsite.com/search/pdf/harry-potter-reviews
```

I need to redirect to:

```
newsite.com/search/docs/harry+potter+reviews
```

The redirect should be 301? (Google safe for moved content).

Answer (score 0):

For a more general approach you could use something like

```
RedirectMatch "^/search/pdf/docs/(.*)" "http://newsite.com/search/docs/$1"
```

or for your specific case

```
Redirect 301 "/search/pdf/harry-potter-reviews" "http://newsite.com/search/docs/harry+potter+reviews"
```

You could also use the mod_rewrite

more info [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're doing two separate mappings: pdf -> docs, and - -> +

If that's accurate you can do this as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteRule (.+)-(.+) $1+$2 [N]
RewriteRule ^search/pdf/(.+) /search/docs/$1 [R=301]
```

The [N] flag says "do it again as long as it still matches", which will result in a global search-and-replace of - with + no matter how many there are. When that's done, it will redirect any 'pdf' URL to 'docs'.

Caveats:

1) I've assumed that you're putting this in a .htaccess file in your document root.

2) + is usually a reserved character in URLs, and there will be situations in which using it will result in Bad Things Happening. You've been warned.